# Retrieving Adjacency-List-Model data excluding an array of defined nodes

Tags: php, sql, recursion, hierarchical-data

Data input format is:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| parent_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| child_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This data defines relations that are used to draw a tree graph, using a DOT script. The DOT is sophisticated enough to handle all the recursion given a link between every node, e.g.

```
1 -> 2;
1 -> 3;
2 -> 4;
4 -> 5;
4 -> 6;
6 -> 7;
```

Will generate:

[image]

I need to exclude branches defined by a blacklist array, e.g. if the blacklist array is `[4]` the DOT script would need to become:

```
1 -> 2;
1 -> 3;
2 -> 4;
```

Comment: Does your DMBS's SQL implementation support recursive queries ?

Answer (score 1):

If your DBMS supports recursive queries you could trim the tree by a recursive query (which could be put into a view or even a function) This example works for Postgres, but could be adapted to MS or Oracle.

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE family
        ( parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , child_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (parent_id,child_id)
        );

INSERT INTO family(parent_id,child_id) VALUES
 (1 , 2) ,(1 , 3)
,(2 , 4)
,(4 , 5) ,(4 , 6)
,(6 , 7)
        ;

CREATE TABLE black_sheep (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO black_sheep(id) VALUES(4);
-- INSERT INTO black_sheep(id) VALUES(6);

WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
        SELECT parent_id AS opa
                , parent_id as dad
                , child_id AS kid
        FROM family f0
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM family nx
                WHERE nx.child_id = f0.parent_id
                )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tr.opa AS opa
                , f1.parent_id AS dad
                , f1.child_id AS kid
        FROM family f1
        JOIN tree tr ON tr.kid = f1.parent_id
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM black_sheep nx
                WHERE nx. id = f1.parent_id
                )
        )
SELECT * FROM tree;
```

Result:

```
 opa | dad | kid 
-----+-----+-----
   1 |   1 |   2
   1 |   1 |   3
   1 |   2 |   4
(3 rows)
```

Comment: In my case it isn't (MySQL), though it is a valid answer.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it cannot be solved at the database side. Your app will have to do the filtering. Extra complication: the deletion of Node#4 will orphanise the subtrees @{5,6}, and since your tree is polyroot (a forest) these orphanised subtrees cound easily be missaken for other roots. Best way would probably be to *first* build the complete tree and *then* chop off the subtrees of the #4 node.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient approach that I managed to come up with.

```
$relations  = $db->query("SELECT `parent_id`, `child_id` FROM `relations` ORDER BY `parent_id` ASC LIMIT 500;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

function filterALMData ($data, array $exclude) {
    while (count($exclude)) {
        $new_exclude = [];
        foreach ($data as $i => $node) {
            if (in_array($node['parent_id'], $exclude)) {               
                $new_exclude[] = $node['child_id'];
                unset($data[$i]);
            }
        }
        $exclude = $new_exclude;
    }
    return $data;
};


$data = filterALMData($relations, [4]);
```

**I am posting this to show what I have tried so far. It is not a favourable answer.**

Comment: Can you add a `var_export($relations)` to your question so it is possible to fiddle with it? Also which parent_id is for the root element? `NULL` or `0`?

Comment: @hakre there is infinite amount of root elements (ie. the data represents more than one tree), which was the main reason why I've spent over an hour with recursive data modelling..

Comment: @hakre what I mean to say, that this data represents a polyroot tree structure. None of the initial roots are known until the fool chain is traversed.